# My bluetooth headset connects/disconnect on Macbook pro continuously after waking from sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, ear-phones

I have a macbook pro 2019 and a Huawei freelace with hall sensor. Now there is no issue when I connect and use it. But once I use the hall sensor to turn off earphone (by touching both the ear pieces against each other) it starts giving trouble when turned on again. I connects and then drop and keeps repeating it continuously until I remove it from my devices list and pair it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved in `Bigsur` update.